# What is "call to ScRegSetValueExW failed for FailureActions"?

Tags: windows, events

On a Windows 7 x64 system I find this entry in my eventlog multiple times after startup and once before shutdown.

Der Aufruf "ScRegSetValueExW" ist für "FailureActions" aufgrund folgenden Fehlers fehlgeschlagen: 
Zugriff verweigert

(The call to "ScRegSetValueExW" has failed for "FailureActions" due to the following reason: Access denied)

I couldn't find anything on any forum, all the search results do list the error as part of the eventlog but none does focus on it as to what it really means and why it appears.
As I have a quite persistent windows update problem (80080005) on this machine i suspect the problems to be related.

Any knowledge about this issue around?

Comment: When you repost this to the correct forum (Super User) please make sure you include full details for the event including Log Name, Source, Event ID, etc.

Comment: reposted. Thanks for the hint